# Trying to find scifi movie title from 80's about long abandoned ship and killer robot

Tags: story-identification

What I remember is they have boarded a long abandoned ship on a planet and they have a robot with them. The robot is a midget with a face like C3PO but no eyes.  There is a robot of the same type that was left on the ship to guard it.  They set their robot to sentry mode(?) and send him after the other robot.

I believe they are trying to use the old ship to escape.  I think the ship had been there for 100 years? The original pilots grandsons help is enlisted to get the ship running but I don't think he had every seen it before.

I am guessing it was an 80s straight to VHS movie as I believe I saw it as a rental in the late 80s possibly early 90s in Canada.

I have gone through many lists of scifi movies in this time frame but can't seem to find it.

Comment: Hello DazedAndConfused and welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack. Thank you for your question. Are there any other details you might remember? What did the rest of the crew look like, for instance? Where did you watch it and in what language? If there's anything else you remember, how insignificant it may seem, you can [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/150263/edit) your question to add it. Meanwhile, may I suggest you take the [tour] to learn more about this site?

Comment: You lost me at the first sentence. Who *they*?

Comment: I have added about as much as I can remember.  Don't know who "they" are, just the robots and abandoned ship on a planet in maybe a mining facility?.  I remember they were concerned about nuclear  power cells being depleted.

Comment: Misremembering *The Black Hole*?....there are some aspects that could relate - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078869/

Comment: @Dazed You should add that information about the ship being on a planet to your post, so that people can rule out stories about a derelict ship floating in space. And at the same time, please add a few paragraph breaks.

Comment: Not The Black Hole.

Comment: I remember the movie in question, but not the title.  It was a British film, I think, with some footage from an Australian rock quarry.  It had a theatrical release in the US.  AND IT STUNK TO HIGH HEAVEN!  "Starship" does sound vaguely familiar.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have found it. Typed vhs sci fi into ebay search and didnt actually have to look to far. Have to watch it to be sure, but the movie title was "Starship" originally and retitled "Lorca and the Outlaws"